# Alternative for multiple IF/CASE statements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, switch-statement

Is there a way to avoid multiple IF/CASE statements in C#?

In my app I will end up with 8+ fields used to create a Linq query where every expression can be null or != null so it will give me 64 scenarios.

I'm not providing any code samples because I can do it using IF/CASE and simplify it as much as I can.

If You are familiar with some useful approaches to that problem I will appreciate any advice.

Code Sample (it only includes two delegates but I'll have to add more to filter data)

**Repository**

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter1 = null)
            {
                IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

                if (filter != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(filter);
                    return query.ToList();
                }

                if (filter1 != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(filter1);
                    return query.ToList();
                }
                else
               {
                    return query.ToList();
               }
            }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchFullName, string searchExtension)
    {
        var extensionList = new List<string>();
        var extensions = from n in unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get()
                         select n.Extension;
        extensionList.AddRange(extensions.Distinct());
        ViewBag.searchExtension = new SelectList(extensionList);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFullName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExtension))
        {
            return View(unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get(n => n.Extension == searchExtension && n.Name.Contains(searchFullName)));
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExtension))
        {
            return View(unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get(n => n.Extension == searchExtension));
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFullName) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExtension))
        {
            return View(unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get());
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFullName) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExtension))
        {
            return View(unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get(n => n.Name.Contains(searchFullName)));
        }
        else
        {
            return View(unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get());
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"I'm not providing any code samples"_ - you really should, because _"8+ fields ... LINQ ... 64 scenarios"_ doesn't make much sense. We'll have to guess what you mean which won't help answer accuracy.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. Include some code in your question, otherwise we can't give you any useful help.

Comment: try switch-case, please provide some code.

Comment: Seriously, if you aren't going to bother to provide code examples, I'm not going to bother to offer advice on avoiding multiple ifs/cases.

Comment: The whole idea was to ask the community a question about potentially different approach to that problem and then try to implement it instead of writing a code that will be 200 lines long and paste it as a part of my question...

Comment: The problem is that problem is so generic that there are 200 possible answers. Your code shows a working approach that can be simplified, as opposed to 200 shots in the dark. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using Linq's powerful `Aggregate` method (a version of the `fold` function from functional programming).

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> FilterOnAll(params Expression<Predicate<T> filters)
{
    return filters.Aggregate(dbSet, (acc, element) => acc.Where(element));
}

public virtual IEnumerable<T> FilterOnAny(params Expression<Predicate<T> filters)
{
    Expression<Predicate<T>> alwaysTrue = _ => true;
    var compositeFilter = filters.Aggregate(alwaysTrue, (acc, element) => acc.Or(element));
    return dbSet.Where(compositeFilter);
}
```

You can then compose these two builders to create pretty much any logical condition you want from within your controller.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is an or statement in your where clause

`where (variable1 == null || b.data =  variable1)`
 and just do that for all 8 if im understanding your problem if its null it passes over it as true else it checks against the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire `if .. elseif .. else` block can be replaced by:

```
return View(unitofwork.DomainRepository.Get(n => 
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFullName)  || n.Name.Contains(searchFullName))
  && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExtension) || n.Extension == searchExtension)));
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint as well. It helped me to solve that problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767115/razor-dropdownlist-for-each-and-all-elements